# How can i add variable to input value using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a variable and i want to add it to an input value

- The variable is names **text**
- Put the **text** variable to the input value

```
<div class="swiper-slide">
    <i class="button fa-regular fa-pen-to-square" id="update_pen" ></i>
    <div class="services-item mb-40 elementor-repeater-item-78d8e80" id="swiper-slide-one">
        <div class="services-item__content">
            <h4 class="services-item__tp-title mb-30" id="h_foor">
                <a href="service-details.html">BIOCHIMIE</a>
            </h4>

            <div class="text_area_box" id="text_area_box">
                <input type="text" name="" required="" value=""> <--- add the variable to this value             
                <label>Titre</label>
            </div>
           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript code :

```
document.querySelectorAll('i.button').forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    var element = document.querySelector(".text_area_box");
    var elementactive = document.querySelector(".text_area_box_active");

    if(element.classList.contains('text_area_box'))  /*the condition works perfectly*/
     {
    
       element.classList.remove('text_area_box');
       element.classList.add('text_area_box_active');
       
     }
    if(elementactive.classList.contains('text_area_box_active')){
    
        elementactive.classList.remove('text_area_box_active');
        elementactive.classList.add('text_area_box');
    }
      const parent = e.target.closest('.swiper-slide');
      const text = parent.querySelector('a').textContent; //this variable

    });
  });
```

i would highely appriciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Salut !
After your

```js
const text = parent.querySelector('a').textContent; //this variable
```

maybe you can try to select your closest input type text and do a myInputelement.val(text) ?

Comment: i would do some kind of parent.children('#text_area_box').val(text);